# Image to HttpPostedFileBase - or a way to store an Image file in server filesystem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a WCF RESTful service that has the purpose of receiving a base64-encoded string that represents an image and store it in the server filesystem, in a manner similar to how a HttpPostedFile does it with the following code (file is a HttpPostedFileBase variable):

```
file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("..\\Content\\UploadedImages\\") + id + file.FileName.Replace(" ",""));
```

So far, I can create an System.Drawing.Image object from the base64 string without any problems. However, I can't seem to create a HttpPostedFileBase variable that can take this image and invoke the method put in the code brackets?

Is there any way I can do it? According to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896640/net-load-file-to-httppostedfilebase), I can't, so the real question would be:

How can I save an System.Drawing.Image file in the filesystem of my server, so I can just keep a reference to the file in the database? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance for your time! :D

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No, but the answer below by Darin works just fine to me. Thanks for the preocupation jgauffin! :)

Comment: Definitely never use ".." in a file path in ASP .NET... it may cause you to be attacked be a Velociraptor and/or expose serious security flaws in your code.  As a general rule, you should always use the "~/Path" (~ signifies the root of your application) syntax.

Comment: Oh crap, I don't want to be attacked by a Velociraptor!! Well, thanks for the warning Jeremy! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) instance you could save it like this on the server inside the `UploadedImages` folder:

```
using (Image image = ...)
{
    var imagesFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadedImages");
    var filename = Path.Combine(imagesFolder, id, file.FileName.Replace(" ",""));
    image.Save(filename);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try to check it out. Thanks for the answer Darin! :D

Comment: Although the Server.MapPath didn't work for me, I found a workaround (I had the server path on hand) and the rest of the code works just fine. Thanks Darin!! :D